# Add 2 additional lines to a ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I have successfully plotted my `dat` below. However, I want to do the following data transformation: `dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% mutate(x.cm = mean(x), x.cwc = x-x.cm)` and then ADD 2 lines to my current plot:

1. `geom_smooth()` using `x.cm` as `x`
2. `geom_smooth()` using `x.cwc` as `x`

Is there a way to do this?

**p.s:** Is it also possible to display the 3 `unique(x.cm)` values as 3 stars on the plot? (*see pic below*)

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/cw.csv')

  dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, color = groups, shape = groups)+
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  stat_ellipse()

# Now do the transformation:
dat %>% group_by(groups) %>% mutate(x.cm = mean(x), x.cwc = x-x.cm)
```

[image]

Comment: Try this, consider that you have different measures: `dat %>% group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate(x.cm = mean(x), x.cwc = x-x.cm) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(y,groups)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, y, color = factor(groups), shape = factor(groups))) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + theme_classic()+ 
  geom_smooth(formula = y~x,se=F)+
  stat_ellipse()+facet_wrap(.~name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the second part of your question makes any sense to me. But from the description one way is to simply add a level where you alter you data and `aes` argument, as I do in the example below (using `mtcars` as an example data)

```
# Load libraries and data
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(cyl))) + 
  stat_ellipse(aes(col = factor(cyl))) + 
  # Add line for ellipsis center
  geom_line(data = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(mean_x = mean(hp),
                                                          mean_y = mean(mpg),
                                                          .groups = 'drop'),
            mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y)) + 
  geom_point(data = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(mean_x = mean(hp),
                                                           mean_y = mean(mpg),
                                                           .groups = 'drop'), 
             mapping = aes(x = mean_x, y = mean_y)) +
  # Add smooth for.. what? I don't understand this part of the question.
  geom_smooth(data = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(x_val = hp - mean(hp)) %>% ungroup(),
              mapping = aes(x = x_val, y = mpg))
```

[image: multipart-plot]

Now it should be quite clear which part does not make sense to me. Why/what do you mean with the second path (`geom_smooth`)? Moving the x-axis on the smoother makes no sense to me. Also I took the liberty of changing the definition of the first part, by instead adding the single points of the mean (center of circles) to the plot and connecting the using `geom_line`.

Comment: The question was more "what to smooth". In your question you are smoothing "x - mean(x)". Since it is in the same visual, it would be adding a smooth to the variable `x` but mean-removed (by group) so the smooth would be shifted towards zero. In case what you are looking for is just a smooth of the ellipsis centers, simply copy the data in `geom_line` or `geom_point` and change it to `geom_smooth´ (equivalent to smoothing over the centers rather than mean-removed points). :-)

Comment: I'd agree `ggplot2` is redundant (I like being visual however). `data(mtcars)` is simply a good habit, to make it obvious to those whom may just be starting out in R, to make it clear I'm not pulling the dataset out of thin air. :-)

Comment: Oliver, I came to the conclusion that I should tackle my question in pieces, for now I accepted your solution (thank you!) but i'll ask some follow-ups in just a bit.